# Google drive - java.io.FileNotFoundException: document.txt (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using the code from the Google Drive API examples to insert a file in Drive which is failing with java.io.FileNotFoundException: document.txt (No such file or directory). I have commented out code that creates a folder in Drive and this works without any problems. So I am authenticated ok. Where am I going wrong.

Kind regards,
Ian.

```
public void saveToDrive(ServletContext sc){
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = getGoogleApiCredential(sc);
        Drive service = getDriveService(googleCredential);
        String parentId = null;
        try {
            About about = service.about().get().execute();
            System.out.println("Current user name: " + about.getName());

            System.out.println("Root folder ID:" + about.getRootFolderId());
            parentId = about.getRootFolderId();
            System.out.println("Total quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesTotal());
            System.out.println("Used quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesUsed());
    }catch (IOException e){

    }

        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("Doc title");
        body.setDescription("A toast document");
        body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.file");
        body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new     ParentReference().setId(parentId)));


        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("plain/text", fileContent);
            //File body = new File();
            //body.setTitle("title");
            //body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");


        try {
            //File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
            File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

            logger.severe("File id: " + file.getId());
        } catch (IOException e) {

        logger.severe(e.toString());
        }


    }
```

Comment: new java.io.File("document.txt");  give it a full path maybe?

Comment: I am setting the Drive parent folder location in body.setParents

Comment: paste the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to completely re-run your scenario, but you may be able to test it with a method I use (so it is tested). The only obvious difference is that I stick THE SAME MIME TYPE in both 'body' and 'content'. Yours are different. Also I don't know what your 'about.getRootFolderId()' produces. You may try to stick "root" string there just to test it.

```
/**********************************************************************
   * create file/folder in GOODrive
   * @param prnId  parent's ID, (null or "root") for root
   * @param titl  file name
   * @param mime  file mime type (optional)
   * @param file  file (with content) to create
   * @return      file id  / null on fail
   */
  static String create(String prnId, String titl, String mime, java.io.File file) {
    String rsid = null;
    if (mGOOSvc != null && titl != null && file != null) {
      File meta = new File();
      meta.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(prnId == null ? "root" : prnId)));
      meta.setTitle(titl);
      if (mime != null)
        meta.setMimeType(mime);

      File gFl = mGOOSvc.files().insert(meta, new FileContent(mime, file)).execute();
      if (gFl != null && gFl.getId() != null) 
        rsid = gFl.getId();
    }
    return rsid;
  }
```

It is taken from a working [CRUD demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/REST.java#L151) here.
Good Luck